# How do I get a control which looks like a TabControl with no tabs?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

We have a form which displays media items in tab pages of a tab control, and I'm implementing a feature which allows users to 'pop out' the tab pages into their own forms.

However, when I add the media player to a form rather than a TabPage, the background switches from the gradient fill of a tab page to the plain SystemColors.Control background of the parent form.  I need to add the the media player to a control which has the same background as a TabControl, but which doesn't display a tab at the top.  I tried adding the media player to the TabControl's control collection, but that just throws an exception.

How do I get a control which looks like a TabControl with no tabs?  Should I keep trying to add the media player to a TabControl, or should I try to write a Panel with a custom-drawn background?  If the latter, how do I make sure that works with all possible themes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Henk - I eventually went with:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (TabRenderer.IsSupported && Application.RenderWithVisualStyles)
    {
        TabRenderer.DrawTabPage(pe.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle);
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(pe);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(pe.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, Border3DStyle.Raised);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your control has background color Transparent, or else you wont get the same looks as the tab control.

Answer (score 3):

The questions seems to be about the UseVisbleBackgroundStyle. AFAIK only buttons and TabPages have this property.

The following is a very dirty hack, just to get you started:

1) derive a customControl from Panel and add "using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;"

2) Add the following code

```
//warning: incomplete, add error checking etc
private readonly VisualStyleElement element = VisualStyleElement.Tab.Body.Normal;
public bool UseVisbleBackgroundStyle { get; set; }

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    if (UseVisbleBackgroundStyle)
    {
        var x = new VisualStyleRenderer(element);                           
        x.DrawBackground(pe.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle);
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own customer UserControl

Comment: OK.. how do I make that look like a TabControl with no tabs?

Comment: A TabControl without tabs, isn't that just a Panel?

Comment: @Svish: No.  A TabControl, even without tabs, has a specific background determined by the user's theme.  In the XP default theme, it's a gradient fill with a border and a drop shadow.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is modified from another [answer site](http://www.aspnet-answers.com/microsoft/Visual-Studio-General/30164969/tab-control-without-tabs.aspx).  It does the trick rather cleanly.

In the load event for the window containing the tab control, try:

```
// TabControl is the name of the tab control in this window.
TabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
TabControl.Multiline = false;
TabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
TabControl.ItemSize = new Size(0,1);

// The tabs are now gone.  Select the panel you want to display
TabControl.SelectTab("InProgressTab");
```